# Swift - TabBarController - Decide segue at runtime

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

i have the following situation:

In my TabBarController i have multiple tabs and it all works fine, but:

The destination of one specific tab is dynamic.

If a certain condition matches, this specific tab should open a NavigationViewController.

If an other condition matches, this specific tab should open a ViewController.

Are there any built in solutions?

How can i modify the destination of a tab at runtime?

Greetings and thanks

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.. how did you solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Long long ago, in a galaxy far far away...
Segues didn't even exist. So yeah

The UITabBarController has a setter in which you can pass the new view controllers you want it to handle. You won't be able to decide what shows at the point of the tapping this way, but you'll be able to change the controllers as the condition changes.

```
open func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?, animated: Bool)
```

If you however DO need to decide as the tab is tapped... You could have your tab controller direct to a controller that's essentially empty, and use view controller containment for that controller to have the 2 options on it, and have one of them hidden. Pretty doable from the storyboard with very little supporting code. I think I prefer this option.

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather continue to use Segues, then you can perform a specific Segue depending on the state of some `condition` variable like this:

```
func presentAppropriateView() {
    if condition {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToNavBar", sender: self)
    } else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToVC", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write a delegate method which you want to perform on certain condition on runtime and call  
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

where index could be of your choice